# documentation for setSpacing in memoir class

Tags: spacing, memoir

It seems correct to insert `\setSpacing{number}` in the preamble of a `memoir` document. But I couldn't find any references for this command in the [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).

I typed `latexdiff setSpacing` in my terminal, and got

```
\setSpacing
undefined
```

Where is the documentation for this command?

Comment: a user is more likely to use `\setSingleSpace{num}` (default is 1)

Comment: Use it as `\setSingleSpace{1.1}\SingleSpacing`

Comment: Where did you get this from? It is not documented in the manual even though it is defined in the class code. It was never thought that an end-user would use it so no need to document it or for anybody to use it.

Comment: @PeterWilson Well [it is used in LyX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6o75.png)... That's how I came across this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple wrapper around the core latex functionality of redefining `\baselinestretch` its definition is just

```
\newcommand*{\setSpacing}[1]{%
  \def\baselinestretch{#1}%
  \@currsize}
```

I assume it's not documented as you would not normally use it directly it is used internally in the definition of the named space adjustments such as `\SingleSpacing` and `\OnehalfSpacing`

Comment: Where did you get this definition from? I would like to be able to rich for it by myself.

Comment: @tush just look in `memoir.cls`. I have it on speed dial in my editor.

Comment: So `\setSpacing{1.3}`, for example, is just the same as `\baselinestretch{1.3}`? What does `@\currsize` do?

Comment: no it is the same as `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.3}` (or as shown above `\def\baselinestretch{1.3}` which is more or less the same thing. `\@currsize` just re-selects the font you last selected so it re-calculates the baseline, eg if you are at `\normalsize` it does `\normalsize` but that will now set the baseline to the normal baseline adjusted by the new factor.